# Insert datagridview column values into an Array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

In my form I have this DataGridView (grid1), filled from a sqllite database. 
[image]

I want select the column with the name "cap" and insert the column's values into an array.
How can I do?

1. I don't find a way to select the column cap by name, so I decided to indicate it with the index, but I don't like this way..
2. I don't know ho to insert these values into an array. there are a lot of columns/cell method but I don't figured out which one can help me!

I tryed to do this way (from an old answer here in the site) but it gives me error of "out of bounded matrix"

```
     int[] wareCap = new int[grid1.Rows.Count];
       ... 
     //How I filled my dgv, if this can help
    var context = new ForliCesenaEntities2(); 
     BindingSource bi1 = new BindingSource();  
    bi1.DataSource = context.warehouses.ToList();
    grid1.DataSource = bi1;
    grid1.Refresh();

    //How I try to insert the values into int[] wareCap 
    for (int i = 0; i<(grid1.Rows.Count-1); i++)
    wareCap[i] = Convert.ToInt16(grid1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: Which DataSource you are using?

Comment: Ah ok see it. Sorry.

Comment: `grid1.Rows[i].Cells["columname"]` should do for your first point

Comment: Check your datagridview's rows count, maybe you need to count to `grid1.Rows.Count - 2`

Comment: Don't datagridviews have a header row as well?

Comment: @stuartd i've done grid1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "cap";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you gridview has to be filled with values, then:

```
List<int> intValues = new List<int>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
    intValues.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells["cap"].Value.ToString()));
}

int[] array = intValues.ToArray();
```

should do the trick.

Alternatively, you could use LINQ.

```
int[] intArray = dataGridView1.Rows
                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Select(row => int.Parse(row.Cells["cap"].Value.ToString())).ToArray();
```

UPDATE:

The above solution might crash if the DataGridView's AllowUserToAddRows property is set to true. Because in that case your last row is the row for entering a new record, the Value is null, so invoking the ToString method on it causes a NullReferenceException.

I see two possibilities:

- set your datagridview's AllowUserToAddRows property to false (but the user won't be able to add new rows),
- use the following solution

Check if the row is the row for entering a new record:

```
int[] intArray = dataGridView1.Rows
                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Where(row => !row.IsNewRow)
                .Select(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["cap"].Value.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: Using you linq suggestion give me and error: "
Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Using your first suggestion , at "DataRow row" gives me error 

Additional information: Unable to cast of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' object type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: "First you gridview has to be filled with values" I've already filled with the data from database...or I have to do something else to fill the dgv?

Comment: You have used DataRow which is used for DataSet and DataTable for data grid view control it must be DatGridViewRow type instead of DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

You already got all your values in a List, because you do sth. like this:

```
bi1.DataSource = context.warehouses.ToList();
```

You can easily store this in a reference:

```
var values = context.warehouses.ToList();
bi1.DataSource = values;
```

Your Grid is build based on Objekts in this List. So this should build your array:

```
int[] array = new int[values.Count];
int counter = 0;
foreach (var object in values)
{
  array[counter++] = object.CAP;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] wareCap = new int[grid1.Rows.Count];
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in grid1.Rows)
{
    wareCap.Add(Convert.ToInt32(cell["cap"].Value.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Error "row.Cells[0]"  the instruction foreach can't work with variables o type "system.windows.form.datagridviewcell" because this don't have a public definition for "get enumerator"